# Cannot set Sobject field value through <apex:InputField> tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am trying to dynamically set mandatory field values of a Sobject and then typecasting it to Campaign object for inserting it to database. Below is the relevant parts of my code.

### Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:outputpanel id="requiredFieldsBlock">
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.MandatoryFieldsPrompt}" rendered="{!isCampaignSelected}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="fieldsTable" title="Mandatoryfields" value="{!MandatoryFieldsWrapperList}" var="mandatoryFieldWrapper">

            <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.MandatoryFields}" value="{!mandatoryFieldWrapper.fieldLabel}" style="width:500px; height: 28px; text-align:center"/> 

            <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.Value}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!campaignToInsert[mandatoryFieldWrapper.fieldApi]}" required="true" style="width: 600px; height: 28px" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!insertCampaignToDb}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-around--large" reRender="requiredFieldsBlock,hiddenBlock" onComplete="removeEmptyErrorMessage()" status="renderLightningSpinner" value="Create Campaign"/>
        <apex:commandButton html-novalidate="novalidate" immediate="true" action="{!back}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-around--large slds-float--right" reRender="errorMessageBlock,hiddenBlock" status="renderLightningSpinner" value="{!$Label.Back}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:outputpanel>
```

### Controller:

```
public with sharing class ImportCampaignsAngularPoCCntrl {
    public Sobject campaignToInsert {get;set;}
    public static List<MandatoryFieldsWrapper> mandatoryFieldsWrapperList 
    {get;set;}
    public ImportCampaignsAngularPoCCntrl() {
      campaignToInsert = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Campaign').newSObject();
      mandatoryFieldsWrapperList = new List <MandatoryFieldsWrapper>();         
    }


public PageReference initialiseMandatoryFieldsBlock() {

    String mandFieldWrapper =             
    Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('mandatoryfieldwrapper');
    mandatoryFieldsWrapperList = new List <MandatoryFieldsWrapper>();       
    mandatoryFieldsWrapperList.clear();
    mandatoryFieldsWrapperList = (List<MandatoryFieldsWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(mandFieldWrapper, List<MandatoryFieldsWrapper>.class);
    finalCampaign = mandatoryFieldsWrapperList.get(0).importedcampaign;
    campaignToInsert = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Campaign').newSObject(); 
    campaignToInsert.put(Schema.Campaign.Name, finalCampaign.Name);
    campaignToInsert.put(Schema.Campaign.crId__c, finalCampaign.crId__c);
    isCampaignSelected = TRUE;
    return null;
}

    public PageReference insertCampaignToDb() { 
        campaignToInsert = (Campaign) campaignToInsert;
        insert campaignToInsert ;
    } 

    public with sharing class MandatoryFieldsWrapper {
        public String fieldLabel {get;set;}
        public String fieldApi {get;set;}
        public Campaign importedcampaign {get;set;}

        public MandatoryFieldsWrapper (String fieldLabel, String fieldApi, 
                                       Campaign importedcampaign) {
            this.fieldLabel = fieldLabel;
            this.fieldApi = fieldApi;
            this.importedcampaign = importedcampaign;        
        }    
    }
}
```

On debugging, I could see that `campaignToInsert` is not getting the field values entered via the VF page. How can I correctly obtain the field values?

Comment: Do you actually set or populate `MandatoryFieldsWrapperList` anywhere?

Comment: I agree with @AdrianLarson I don't see you setting MandatoryFieldsWrapperList anywhere in you controller. If you haven't done that then that could cause some issues.

Comment: @AdrianLarson. Yup I do. I have updated my controller code to include that part.

Comment: @DanKowalski. I pass in a wrapper object named **mandatoryfieldwrapper** from VisualForce page via **<apex:actionFunction>** and use it to populate **MandatoryFieldsWrapperList**

Comment: I got where I am going wrong. It was the **static** keyword. Unlike normal static keyword, Salesforce static is only static withing the context on which it is used. After, it'll again be reset to null. I was using a lot of remote actions and overlooked the unwanted static keyword. Removed it now and the issue is fixed.